# Display strapi fields instead of id

Tags: node.js, strapi

I am developing one project using strapi.

I have created one dynamic component with the following structure.
[image]

I have added this component in one of my collections called "Markup" which is single-type collection.

When I add some data in markup collection like this:
[image]

Here, instead of id of component I want to display range.

for example,

[image]

In the above screenshot, strapi is displaying "1" in component header. I want to replace it with something like this: `${min}-${max}`.
so, instead of "1" it should display "5-9.9" and instead of "2" it should display "10-24.99"

How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created one new field called `displayName` in the component and set it to `${min}-${max}` when a user updates an entry in the component record and then sets the field `displayName` to display field from strapi view configuration.